# Concurrent connections and Prefork MPM module

Tags: ubuntu, httpd, apache2

I'm testing my server to know how many concurrent connections it support. I configure my `mpm_prefork.conf` this way:

```
# prefork MPM
# StartServers: number of server processes to start
# MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxRequestWorkers: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
# MaxConnectionsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers             5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxRequestWorkers     100000
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

But when my server receives ~8200 concurrent connections, an error is fired and apache not respond anymore:

```
[notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

The server has enough memory left.

Is the configuration ok? Do I have to change anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might be  running into your systems process limit. Check with `ulimit -u` and see [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/356962/where-are-the-default-ulimit-values-set-linux-centos).

Comment: Returns 15586...

Comment: I change to 50000 in /etc/security/limits.conf and still fail with ~8000 users