# Where does Linux get ulimit values for certain users?

Tags: linux, debian, ulimit

I see that different users in my Debian system has different max open files limits. I read [the post](https://serverfault.com/questions/356962/where-are-the-default-ulimit-values-set-linux-centos) but would like to get some understanding of the details. I do not have any settings into `/etc/security/limits.conf` but:

**mysql** seems to follow kernel values:

```
Max open files            1024                 4096
```

**redis** has different values:

```
Max open files            4096                 4096
```

Does it raise it by default with `setrlimit` call?

**root** has another values:

```
Max open files            65536                65536
```

Are the special root values hardcoded somewhere or where should I seek for the settings?

Comment: Do you have /etc/security/limits.d/*? Also Is there a init script or something else getting called during start up? If it is application specific maybe it could be set during the start up of that service.

Comment: No, this folder is empty but at least found out in redis logs that it raises the soft limit on its own.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it raise it by default with setrlimit call?

Probably. Applications may attempt to change their limits with that call.

On Linux, increasing above the hard limit requires CAP_SYS_RESOURCE privilege, see the man page. In practice, this means that running init scripts as root allows them to exceed this kind of resource limit.